# How to prefix folders and files within?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, batch-rename

I'm stuck looking for a one-liner to add a prefix to all subfolder names and file names in a directory

eg "AAA" in the examples below

/folder/AAAfile.txt

/folder/AAAread/AAAdoc.txt

/folder/AAAread/AAAfinished/AAAread.txt

I've tried using xargs and find, but can't get them to go recursively through the subdirectories and their contents. Any suggestions?
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like that

`find . -mindepth 1 | sort -r | xargs -l -I {} bash -c 'mv $1 ${1%/*}/AAA${1##*/}' _ {}`

Tested with your folder structure, executed from the root (same as AAAfile.txt).

Comment: Good use of parameter expansion with substring removal, and the reverse sort to protect against a directory rename before the files within.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should meet your need (ran it from inside your `folder` directory):

```
for i in `ls -R`;do
        dname=`dirname $i`
        fname=AAA`basename $i`
        if [ -f $i ]
        then
                mv $i $dname/$fname
        fi
        #this could be merged with previous condition but have been kept just to avoid invalid directory warning
        if [ -d $i ]
        then
                mv $i $dname/$fname
        fi
done
```